# Android Opengl 2 shapes with different colors

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors, textures, shapes

I am a newbie with opengl on android. I am trying to draw two different shapes. Shape one has a texture while shape two is supposed to have a color, lets say green. When I run the application, the first shape gets its texture but has also the green color. The texture itself is turned greenish in color. Shape two is green as i wanted. Here is my draw method:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    //My first shape

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glPushMatrix();

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    //My second shape
    gl.glPushMatrix();
            //Setting the color green
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, locvertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, locvertices.length / 3);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put  `gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);`  before  drawing the first shape

**OR**

use `gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_REPLACE);`

after you bind the texture